# is there a way to modify part of file but keep reading the whole file

Tags: python, file, multiple-columns

i have an input file for code system, the file contains symbols, integers, texts and float numbers. 
and i have another file contains 2 columns.
no specific pattern for the file. some part are only text, other like array, other like columns. 
my concern is i want to modify specific columns. i already have a code module to modify the columns. its reading from another file and change the values in another file.

the problem is, it is just reading the specific columns. it ignores the data before or after.

the data in file 1 like this:

```
       ag-109 4.778E-08
       am-241 3.525E-08
       am-243 1.157E-11
       cs-133 3.820E-06
       eu-151 1.546E-08
       eu-153 1.086E-07
       gd-155 1.018E-08
       mo-95 3.650E-06
       nd-143 3.300E-06
```

the data looks like this in file 2:

```
        csas6
        gbc-32-keno6
        ce_v7_endf
        read composition
        ........
        (some text and numbers)
        .......
        h-1         10  0 0.0667    293   end
        zr          11  0  0.0432   293   end 
        u-234       101 0 7.471e-06 293   end   #  the columns
        u-235       101 0 0.0005265 293   end   #  that i want
        u-236       101 0 0.0001285 293   end   # to change from 
        u-238       101 0 0.02278   293   end   # another file
        np-237      101 0 1.018e-05 293   end 
        pu-238      101 0 2.262e-06 293   end
        pu-239      101 0 0.000147  293   end
        pu-240      101 0 4.138e-05 293   end
        pu-241      101 0 2.028e-05 293   end
```

columns are like 500 lines after that, its different columns i don't want to change it, then a text and arrays.

i already have another file with two columns, to change the column 1 and 4 from the above file.

Thanks to @Serge he helped for this module, it works for changing. but if there is text before the columns it does not work.

i want to stop changing when column 2 become '201'

after that i want to continue reading the file and save it in another file after modifying.

how i can modify the file and save the whole file after changing.

```
with open('file2') as f2, open('file1') as f1, open('out.txt','w') as fout:
    sep = re.compile(r'\s+')    # compile the separator for re
    while True:
        # read a line from each file
        try:
            line1 = next(f1)
            line2 = next(f2)
        except StopIteration:
            break                # stop processing on end of any file

        # split lines in fields
        fields1 = sep.split(line1.strip())
        fields2 = sep.split(line2.strip())

        if fields2[1] == '201':
            break                # stop processing if past 101

        # replace fields and write a line on the output file    
        fields2[0] = fields1[0]
        fields2[3] = fields1[1]
        fout.write(' {}      {}  {}  {}  {}   {} \n'.format(*fields2))
```

the expected results should be similar to this:

```
        csas6
        gbc-32-keno6
        ce_v7_endf
        read composition
        ........
        (some text and numbers)
        .......
        ag-109      101 0 4.778E-08 293   end    
        am-241      101 0 3.525E-08 293   end   
        am-243      101 0 1.157E-11 293   end    
        cs-133      101 0 3.820E-06 293   end   
        eu-151      101 0 1.546E-08 293   end 
        eu-153      101 0 1.086E-07 293   end
        gd-155      101 0 1.018E-08  293   end
        mo-95       101 0 3.650E-06 293   end
        nd-143      101 0 3.300E-06 293   end 
        ............ #( another columns stops when column 2 ='201'
        ...............
        # mixture of text, arrays numbers....
```

Comment: You're reading the 2 files in line sync. Is there some kind of marker that identifies when the columns begin so that you can skip the text before the columns?

Comment: @will, i have modified my question, the data in file 2 
i want to start when column 1 is 'u-234' 
i want to skip from 'zr'  and above 
and also i want to continue reading after column 2 is equal '201' 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add another while cycle without if condition in the end, to iterate to end file,
smth like this:

```
with open('file2') as f2, open('file1') as f1, open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
sep = re.compile(r'\s+')    # compile the separator for re
while True:
    # read a line from each file
    try:
        line1 = next(f1)
        line2 = next(f2)
    except StopIteration:
        break                # stop processing on end of any file

    # split lines in fields
    fields1 = sep.split(line1.strip())
    fields2 = sep.split(line2.strip())

    if fields2[1] == '201':
        break                # stop processing if past 101

    # replace fields and write a line on the output file
    fields2[0] = fields1[0]
    fields2[3] = fields1[1]
    fout.write(' {}      {}  {}  {}  {}   {} \n'.format(*fields2))
while True:
    # read a line from each file
    try:
        line1 = next(f1)
        line2 = next(f2)
    except StopIteration:
        break                # stop processing on end of any file

    # split lines in fields
    fields1 = sep.split(line1.strip())
    fields2 = sep.split(line2.strip())

    # if fields2[1] == '201':
    #     break                # stop processing if past 101

    # replace fields and write a line on the output file
    fields2[0] = fields1[0]
    fields2[3] = fields1[1]
    fout.write(' {}      {}  {}  {}  {}   {} \n'.format(*fields2))
```